# dynamically generate headings and rows reactjs using map - nested

Tags: reactjs, nested, iteration

I looked for similar issues but couldnt find a solution.
I am able to generate the headings column and the rows with the values.
but since they are done separately, the alignment is off.
so, is there a way to make it better aligned or maybe nest it in a way that only trowz is enough?? without the iteration being done in tvalues separately?

here's the related code

```
 let keysForSalaryMonth=Object.keys(this.props.stateprops.salarysheet[this.props.stateprops.salaryForMonth]);
    let salaryProperties = Object.keys(this.props.stateprops.salarysheet[this.props.stateprops.salaryForMonth][keysForSalaryMonth[0]]);
    let salaryObj = this.props.stateprops.salarysheet[this.props.stateprops.salaryForMonth];
    console.log(salaryObj[keysForSalaryMonth[0]][name]);
  const trowz = (<table><th>
    {salaryProperties.map((item)=>
      <td>{item}</td>
    )}
    </th>
     </table>
  );

  const tvalues = (<table>
     { keysForSalaryMonth.map((epf)=>{
      return  (<tr>
       {salaryProperties.map((prprty)=>
      <td>{salaryObj[epf][prprty]} </td> 

      )}
    </tr>)
    }
    )}

      </table>);

    return(
      <div>
        {trowz}
      {tvalues}
        </div>
    )
  }
```

the intended html is somewhat like this

```
<table>
<th><td>name</td><td>amount</td>wages</td></th>
<tr><td>Jack</td><td>34543</td>39999</td>

  </table>
```

and it is coming like that too.
the problem is that the column names are not aligned with the column values as they are not the same length.
so, how do I get them to be aligned properly?

at the moment, it looks like this
[image]

I do have an idea now of why this was happening.
I think it could be because both trowz and tavalues are in different tables.
Now, I am trying to put them in the same table but it's not working

here's the revised format of how it looks now, when I try to put it in the same table. 
Please tell me where I am going wrong.

```
const trowz = (<th>
    {salaryProperties.map((item)=>
      <td>{item}</td>
    )}
    </th>

  );
  const tvalues =( keysForSalaryMonth.map((epf)=>{
     return   salaryProperties.map((prprty)=>
      <tr>  <td>{salaryObj[epf][prprty]} </td> </tr>

    )})
  );

    return(
      <table>
        {trowz}
     {tvalues}
        </table>
    )
  }
```

@A Iglesias, your solution makes it look like this
[image]
which is similar to what i was getting with the edited code above.

the generated html

```
 <table>
<th>
<td>name</td><td>epf</td><td>hra</td><td>days</td><td>wagesrate</td><td>basicSalary</td><td>totalWages</td><td>totalAmountPayable</td><td>da</td><td>totalAmount</td><td>pfValue</td><td>esiValue</td><td>totalDeduction</td>
</th>
<tbody>
<tr><td>pintu</td><td>98798789</td><td>902</td><td>2</td><td>8789</td><td>987987</td><td>17578</td><td>18033</td><td>454.6</td><td>18935</td><td>2164</td><td>331</td><td>2495</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you add your intended `HTML` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you say and show, the content is ok, is just a formatting problem. And for want it makes more sense to me to have the information organized in a single table, so you can go with...

```
return (
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        {salaryProperties.map((item,i) => (
          <th key={i}>{item}</th>
        ))}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {keysForSalaryMonth.map((epf,i) => (
        <tr key={i}>
          {salaryProperties.map((prprty,j) => (
            <td key={j}>{salaryObj[epf][prprty]}</td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
)
```

You should choose a better option for the `key` of each element instead of the map index value. Get one that makes sense for the content of the element.

Comment: well, not quite.
it's very much out of alignment. 
i shared a picture of what it looks like when I use your solution in my question above.

Comment: Can you please show the generated html of the table?

Comment: added the generated html.
removed the <thead> as I was trying to see if removing that helps, but it didnt.

Comment: Upps!! Sorry, I set the table header tr,th elements wrong!! I've edited the answer